# Launch skype from an android app on tablet

Tags: android

I am in the process of developing with android studio on LINUX (kubuntu), in java code .
I would like to launch skype from an application.
I use
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype4life", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
myContext.startActivity(myIntent);

When i run the application on my tablet device (not virtual) samsung galaxy tab s2 android version 7.0,
i get the message "unfortunately the application has stopped to working".

when i replace com.skype.raider with com.skype4life, play store is launched and loading icon keeps spinning (no response).

Could some one help me?
Thanks.

In the log cat i found the followings errors:

2022-07-20 06:42:30.000 3208-3783/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 312 [2022-07-20 06:42:30.000]
2022-07-20 06:42:32.570 13291-13291/com.limbani.aauSkype E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2022-07-20 06:42:32.765 13291-13291/com.limbani.aauSkype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.limbani.aauSkype, PID: 13291
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.skype.android/com.skype.android.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1815)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1531)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4403)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4362)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4686)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4654)
at com.limbani.aauSkype.MainActivity.SkypeUri(MainActivity.java:105)
at com.limbani.aauSkype.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6257)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11149)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23705)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1500)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1390)

I found the solution!
I commented the line
//myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));

Here is my code to launch a call

```
public void SkypeUri(Context myContext, String mySkypeUri) {

        // Make sure the Skype for Android client is installed.
        if (!isSkypeClientInstalled(myContext)) {
            Log.i("SkypeUri", "Before goToMarket");
            goToMarket(myContext);
            Log.i("SkypeUri", "After goToMarket");
            return;
        }
        Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
        Log.i("dest",skypeUri.toString());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
        //myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myContext.startActivity(myIntent);
        return;

    }
```

Is an explication of this workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch skype by package name:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider"));
```

Comment: First there was an error in my code,  [ComponentName("com.skype4life", "com.skype.raider.Main"));]  has to replaced with [ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));] . if I use package name as you suggested i get the same issue as :   "applicationname  has stopped to working".

Comment: Could you give me an example of complete java code to launch skype?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know if a certain app is installed, then you need to know the package name. According to the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuritutorial_androidapps

```
/**
* Determine whether the Skype for Android client is installed on this 
  device.
*/
public boolean isSkypeClientInstalled(Context myContext) {
    PackageManager myPackageMgr = myContext.getPackageManager();
    try {
           myPackageMgr.getPackageInfo("com.skype.raider", 
           PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
           return (false);
        }
    return (true);
}
```

If skype app is not installed then:

```
/**
 * Install the Skype client through the market: URI scheme.
*/
public void goToMarket(Context myContext) {
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.skype.raider");
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    myContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    return;
}
```

Below code to open skype

```
/**
  * Initiate the actions encoded in the specified URI.
*/
public void initiateSkypeUri(Context myContext, String mySkypeUri) {

    // Make sure the Skype for Android client is installed.
    if (!isSkypeClientInstalled(myContext)) {
        goToMarket(myContext);
        return;
    }

    // Create the Intent from our Skype URI.
    Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);

    // Restrict the Intent to being handled by the Skype for Android client only.
    myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Initiate the Intent. It should never fail because you've already established the
    // presence of its handler (although there is an extremely minute window where that
    // handler can go away).
    myContext.startActivity(myIntent);

    return;
}
```

Comment: "Determine whether the Skype for Android client is installed on this 
  device." You means the SKYPE application or a set of librairies for client Skype?

Comment: the skype app, or better this package: "com.skype.raider"